# Qt application deployment

Tags: c++, qt

What are the necessary dll files to deploy an application using Qt? By necessary I mean those who are common to all applications, not the entire dll folder. Are msvr120.dll and msvc120.dll necessary too? Thanks to further answers.

Comment: It depends on which Qt modules you use.

Comment: The necessary dlls are those you link your application with. You should distribute them with your executable, as you cannot expect anybody to have Qt dlls installed.

Comment: The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) about Windows deployment is very comprehensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [**Dependency Walker**](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is your best friend in this case.

In short, it depends on how many Qt modules you used in your project.

Check your project file, for example:

```
QT       += core gui script
```

Then you will need

> QtCore4.dll / Qt5Core.dll (QtCored4.dll / Qt5Cored.dll for debug)
>   QtGui4.dll  / Qt5Gui.dll
>   QtScript4.dll / Qt5Script.dll

which can be found in **bin** folder under Qt directory.

---

As for **msvr120.dll** and **msvc120.dll**. You may distribute them as well, in case your user's Windows system doesn't have them (e.g. older version like Windows XP, but I am not sure whether those dlls work in older version of Windows)

Comment: That's just part of the story. You then need the platform plugin, possibly other Qt plugins (image, database, whatever), possibly the MSVC runtime, possibly the ANGLE libs (and thus d3d libs too), and so on.

Comment: @peppe Yeah. I just propose a general situation. Using Dependency Walker is the most reliable way in every case.

Comment: @Tay2510 Unfortunately this is not a general solution (not only because depends.exe is old and buggy). It won't show all your Qt dependencies. Lots of functionality are placed in plugins for whatever reason, and even though they look like normal DLLs they aren't, and won't show up in the imports of your exe so no chance for depends to see them.

Comment: @TamásSzelei It can see the plugins when you specify to profile the `.exe`. It will look for `LoadLibrary` calls and delayed loads and display them too. Check out my PowerShell script to automate the search: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/powershell-script-to-automate-the-search-of-dll-files

Comment: `QtXCore.dll` does not match the file names in Qt 4. For example we have `QtCore4.dll` or `QtGui4.dll` there.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Qt installations include `windeployqt.exe` deployment helper which will copy `Qt`(and `MinGW` if you use it) library `.dll`s. Check your Qt installation directory, it's in same as `qmake.exe`

Basic usage from `cmd`: (Replace `--debug` with `--release` for release builds)

```
mkdir Deploy
copy /y /path/to/exe Deploy
cd Deploy 
windeployqt.exe --debug Prog.exe
```

Aside from required `.dll` files it will also put optional plugins, translation files and configuration files for everything. You can later remove non needed files and `upx` the rest.

Additional info here: [Qt for Windows - Deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) (thanks peppe for link). `windeployqt.exe` is mentioned at the bottom of the page.

Note: It can't deploy `MSVC` runtime libraries. You need a redistrubutable for them, so you can silently install them with your installer.

Comment: `windeployqt.exe` sounds nice. Is that Qt 5 exclusive?

Comment: @Tay2510 it was added along with deployer for android